# Move the image by dragging the image to the right and left

Tags: javascript

I use the following code to display images, but you cannot drag the image to move it and display the next image

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }
  function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  }
  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
 }
 setInterval(plusSlides, 5000, 1); // call plusSlider, with 1 as parameter
```

Comment: Well, nothing in your code is attempting to add a manual "next image" functionality. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't have enough experience

Comment: Then I suggest to check examples of the drag event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/drag_event